# SQL for Joining tables after concatination

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have two tables, Table A and Table B.

### Table A

```
Col1
----------
one.1.1
two.2.2
three.2.2
one.1
one.3
```

### Table B

```
| Col1   | Col2 | Col3 |
+----------------------+
| one    | 1    | 1    |
| two    | 2    | 2    |
| three  | 2    | 1    |
| three  | 2    | 2    |
```

I wanted a left join in which it displays the values which are present in table A but not in table B.
I need to concatenate the Table B columns it can be both in formats "Col1.Col2" or "Col1.Col2.Col3"

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM TableA AS A 
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1+'.'+B.Col2+'.'+B.Col3
WHERE A.Col1 IS NOT NULL
     AND B.Col1+'.'+B.Col2+'.'+B.Col3 IS NULL
```

Comment: Did either of these answers help? If not, please edit your question with more information. Otherwise it's helpful to other users to mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MySQL query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc6835/5)) will do what you want. Note that in MySQL you use `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` to join strings. Also note you only need to check if `B.col1` is `NULL`.

```
SELECT A.Col1
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.Col1 = CONCAT_WS('.', B.Col1, B.Col2, B.Col3) OR
   A.Col1 = CONCAT_WS('.', B.Col1, B.Col2)
WHERE B.Col1 IS NULL
```

Output:

```
Col1
one.3
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it worked but as i am using Ms access i cannot use CONCAT or CONCAT_WS. Instead of CONCAT I am using +

Comment: Cool. You did tag MySQL on the question so that was why I gave a MySQL query. But easy enough to change the CONCAT into a + I guess! :)

Comment: Yes Nick, I could do that.Thanks for guiding

Answer (score 0):

If you use left joined  table's column in where condition this work as an inner join  .. keep the condition in on clause

In your case is you need  the rows that don't match just use them

```
SELECT Col1 FROM TableA AS A 
LEFT JOIN TableB as B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1+'.'+B.Col2+'.'+B.Col3   
WHERE B.Col1+'.'+B.Col2+'.'+B.Col3 IS NULL
```